# MAX(), GROUP BY errors

Tags: db2, max

On DB2 V9 Z/Os

The query below three rows.

```
SELECT J01_REGION, I20_MMS_NO, I20_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CASE_ID,
I42_FIN_MGR_PROV, J01_PROVIDER, I21_CASE_OPEN_DT, I42_FM_BEG_DT
FROM SERDB.I20_CONSUMER_T INNER JOIN SERDB.I21_CONS_CASE_T ON I20_CONSUMER_ID = 
I21_CONSUMER_ID
INNER JOIN SERDB.I42_FIN_MGR_T ON I21_CASE_ID = I42_CASE_ID 
INNER JOIN SERDB.J01_PROVIDER_T ON I42_FIN_MGR_PROV = J01_PROVIDER
WHERE J01_REGION = 2
AND I20_CONSUMER_ID = 96603
```

What I would like is for the query to return just one row by using the MAX values for I21_CASE_OPEN_DT & I42_FM_BEG_DT. If I use:

```
SELECT J01_REGION, I20_MMS_NO, I20_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CASE_ID,  MAX 
(I21_CASE_OPEN_DT), MAX(I42_FM_BEG_DT), I42_FIN_MGR_PROV, J01_PROVIDER
FROM SERDB.I20_CONSUMER_T INNER JOIN SERDB.I21_CONS_CASE_T ON I20_CONSUMER_ID = 
I21_CONSUMER_ID 
INNER JOIN SERDB.I42_FIN_MGR_T ON I21_CASE_ID = I42_CASE_ID 
INNER JOIN SERDB.J01_PROVIDER_T ON I42_FIN_MGR_PROV = J01_PROVIDER
WHERE J01_REGION = 2
AND I20_CONSUMER_ID = 96603;
```

I receive: SQL0122N  A SELECT statement with no GROUP BY clause contains a column name or expression and a column function in the SELECT clause, or a column name or expression is contained in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY clause.  SQLSTATE=42803

If I use:

```
SELECT J01_REGION, I20_MMS_NO, I20_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CASE_ID,
I42_FIN_MGR_PROV, J01_PROVIDER, I21_CASE_OPEN_DT, I42_FM_BEG_DT
FROM SERDB.I20_CONSUMER_T INNER JOIN SERDB.I21_CONS_CASE_T ON I20_CONSUMER_ID = 
I21_CONSUMER_ID 
INNER JOIN SERDB.I42_FIN_MGR_T ON I21_CASE_ID = I42_CASE_ID 
INNER JOIN SERDB.J01_PROVIDER_T ON I42_FIN_MGR_PROV =  J01_PROVIDER
WHERE J01_REGION = 2
AND I20_CONSUMER_ID = 96603
AND MAX(I21_CASE_OPEN_DT)
AND MAX(I42_FM_BEG_DT);
```

I recieve: SQL0199N  The use of the reserved word "AND" following "AND" is not valid.  Expected tokens may include:  "MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES MINUTE HOURS".  SQLSTATE=42601

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what else I could do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second error tells you all you need to know:

> A SELECT statement with no GROUP BY clause contains a column name or expression and a column function in the SELECT clause, or a column name or expression is contained in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY clause

If you use aggregates (`MAX`, `MIN`, etc.) you must group by all other fields in the select statement, which you have not done.

Taking your second query, and adding the GROUP BY clause gets us this:

```
SELECT J01_REGION, I20_MMS_NO, I20_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CASE_ID,  
    MAX (I21_CASE_OPEN_DT), MAX(I42_FM_BEG_DT), I42_FIN_MGR_PROV, J01_PROVIDER
FROM SERDB.I20_CONSUMER_T INNER JOIN SERDB.I21_CONS_CASE_T ON I20_CONSUMER_ID = 
I21_CONSUMER_ID 
INNER JOIN SERDB.I42_FIN_MGR_T ON I21_CASE_ID = I42_CASE_ID 
INNER JOIN SERDB.J01_PROVIDER_T ON I42_FIN_MGR_PROV = J01_PROVIDER
WHERE J01_REGION = 2
    AND I20_CONSUMER_ID = 96603
GROUP BY J01_REGION, I20_MMS_NO, I20_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CONSUMER_ID, I21_CASE_ID,
    I42_FIN_MGR_PROV, J01_PROVIDER;
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. While I did not receive an error, the query still returned three rows.

Comment: Then there are values between the three rows that are causing the rows to be distinct.  You should remove the columns that contain different data per row, and if you **need** those columns, you should revisit what you are trying to accomplish.