# TSM DB2 SQL query for display backup vm

Tags: sql, db2, tivoli

Need some help with below TSM SQL statement to display backup status and to group by the output using the column. Can someone help me with correct SQL query to do display the output using group by. It is failing with error ANS80001I return code 3

```
 select 
   SUB_ENTITY
  ,SCHEDULE_NAME
  ,ACTIVITY_TYPE
  ,SUCCESSFUL
  ,SUBSTR(CHAR(start_time),1,19) AS START_TIME
  ,SUBSTR(CHAR(END_TIME),1,19) AS END_TIME
  ,cast(float(bytes)/1024/1024 as DEC(15)) as MB 
from  SUMMARY_EXTENDED 
 where START_TIME>current_timestamp - 18 hours 
   and SCHEDULE_NAME like '%abcdf' 
   and SUB_ENTITY IS NOT NULL 
   and SUB_ENTITY <> 'Aggregate' 
group by sub_entity,schedule_name,SUCCESSFUL
```

I am expecting an output sub_entity  activity type   start_time end_time Successful

Comment: You can't use columns in the SELECT list not used in the GROUP BY clause outside of aggregation functions. In your case it's wrong use of the `ACTIVITY_TYPE`, `start_time`, `END_TIME`, `bytes` columns in the SELECT list. You must use them inside some agg functions like SUM, MAX, COUNT there only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAX(), GROUP BY errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078098/max-group-by-errors)

Comment: Why is oracle tagged here. as the query relates to TSM/DB2 ?   Instead of querying TSM tables directly (for information relating to Db2 backups), you might instead use the interfaces for the Db2 recovery history, for example with Db2-LUW the DB_HISTORY admin view (unless you want to view non-pruned stuff in TSM).

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.